# Issues in getting Synergy setup

Tags: synergy

For some reason I cannot get things working when the Linux box is the server and the macbook pro is the client.  However I can get things working just fine in the inverse, unfortunately since the macbook is not the primary machine, and not powered on all the time, the later setup won't work.

<strike>Here is the error that I am getting</strike>:
It just hangs when trying to connect:
    started client
    connecting to '10.0.1.4': 10.0.1.4:24800

The only firewall that I have is the one on the router, so since things work with the macbook as the server I am pretty sure that is not where the problem is.

Here is the .synergy.conf file

```
section: screens
  Chris-MacBook-Pro:  # I have tried this with the .local as well
  chris-archlinux.local:
end
section: links
  Chris-MacBook-Pro:
    right = chris-archlinux.local
  chris-archlinux.local:
    left = Chris-MacBook-Pro.local
end
```

** Update:
I should also add that I can ping the linux machine from the mac.  To try get things working, I have also prevented the hosts.deny/.allow files from blocking anything.

An ideas to where the problem could be?

Comment: Can you describe more what it is that isn't working? The "error" you quote is not an error at all. You may want to try turning up the log settings much higher.

Comment: You are right there was no error, it was at that point it said connection wasn't able to be made.  I have made the corrections to that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like a firewall issue. You could try running netstat -an on the linux server to see if synergy is correctly listening, if it is you should see a line like this.

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:24800           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Also, the server side doesn't print anything? If the server is daemonizing itself you should run it with the -f option so it runs in the foreground and you can see its messages.